# Remove dot marks from textarea

Tags: javascript, html, css, textarea

How to remove right bottom-corner dots from textarea ?

[image]

There is a solution with following css `resize:none` but I don't want to remove resizing...

So is it possible to do ...

Comment: Well, you can't have both. Either you can resize it and have the dots, or you can't resize it, and also won't have the dots...

Comment: Corner dots may appear only on textarea hover. If such way suits you, I think it will be pretty simple to acheive with pure CSS.

Comment: I mean you could make white CSS-triangle at the corner and hide it on hover to be able to resize textarea

Comment: so you don't want the user to be able to resize the text area? right

Comment: No Ben, I want the user to be able to resize but the dot marks will not be show...

Comment: There is reason why browsers behave like this. Having a resizable textarea but having no indication/drag handle is **bad UX**. Browsers add this icon for a reason, and these patterns should *generally* not be broken.

Comment: Why would you want a resizable textarea, but not want to indicate that it is resizable?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

try these two ways:

```css
.none::-webkit-resizer {
    display: none;
}
.pic::-webkit-resizer {
    background:    url(http://www.zhangxinxu.com//study/image/selection.gif);
    outline: 1px dotted #000;
}
```

```html
<textarea class="none"></textarea>
<textarea class="pic"></textarea>
```

Comment: Your first example is what I want but it's working in `-webkit-` browsers only , what about firefox etc...

Comment: You should be able to use resize: none; /* disables resizability */  for Firefox as well. http://jsfiddle.net/5c5bqLwt/

Answer (score 6):

You can't remove resize handle without `resize:none;` property. But you can position a `div` on those dotted lines(resize handles). See Demo here

```css
textarea {
    position: relative;
    margin: 20px 0 0 20px;
    z-index: 1;
}
.wrap {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}

.handle-hide {
    height:12px;
    width:12px;
    position: absolute;background:#fff;
    bottom: 2px;
    right: 2px;
    pointer-events: none;
    z-index: 2;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
    <div class="handle-hide"></div>
    <textarea placeholder="drag the cyan triangle..."></textarea>
</div>
```

Comment: Right now I'm waiting for better solution If it is possible with only textarea instead of extra div etc...

Answer (score 4):

Using jQuery this is possible, I found a jQuery UI [here](http://jqueryui.com/resizable/#textarea)

With this source code you're able customize the textarea

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>jQuery UI Resizable - Textarea</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <style>
  .ui-resizable-se {
    bottom: 17px;
  }
  </style>
  <script>
  $(function() {
    $( "#resizable" ).resizable({
      handles: "se"
    });
  });
  </script>
</head>
<body>

<textarea id="resizable" rows="5" cols="20"></textarea>


</body>
</html>
```

Simply override the CSS by adding

```
<style>
    .ui-icon, .ui-widget-content .ui-icon {
    background-image: none;
    }
</style>
```

**after**:

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
```

Answer (score 3):

Have you considered a masking solution?

Here's a basic example (tested only on Chrome):

```
textarea {
    border: 1px solid #000;
    box-shadow: inset .3em 0 #000, 
                inset -.3em 0 #000,
                inset 0 .3em #000,
                inset 0 -.3em #000;
    padding: 10px;
}
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/onzqnk5v/

---

UPDATE (based on comments):

This answer is just a concept for consideration. The example code is meant to illustrate the concept, not serve as a final solution.

Comment: That doesn't mask anything at all!

Comment: This doesn't mask anything indeed. Dots are still visible through the shadow (Chrome)

Comment: @RickDoesburg, I think you may have misunderstood my answer. It's a concept only. An idea that the OP may want to consider. The example was just a basic illustration of the concept and is not meant to be a final solution.

Answer (score 3):

*Hello There **[HERE](http://codepen.io/T04435/pen/zvLPpL)** is a working example of my answer:*

First is to point this is based on CSS3 [resize](http://caniuse.com/#search=resize), which is not fully supported in all browsers.

```
HTML 

<div class="resize_this">
    <textarea class="no_dots"></textarea>
</div>

ENDS HTML

CSS3
.no_dots{
  resize: none;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border:none;
}

.resize_this{
  resize:both;
  overflow: hidden;
  border:2px solid black;
  border-radius: 5px;
/*HERE PLACE DEFAULT SIZE FOR THE TEXTAREA*/
  width: 50%;
  height: 250px;
}
ENDS CSS3
```

**HOPE THIS HELPS** ***[T04435](https://github.com/T04435)***

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I did. You can wrap the `textarea` with an element(for example `span`) and etc. See [my demo](http://jsfiddle.net/r8f40ohs/1/). I did not use any javascript or jquery, For tricky part I use pointer-events which is supported by [most browser](http://caniuse.com/#feat=pointer-events).

Comment: I mentioned in my question "**I don't want to remove resizing**" and also why have to add two `textarea`

Comment: @om. Do you want to disable the re-sizing feature?

Comment: No, Simply I want to remove dots, means it will looks like a textbox but it should be resizable

Comment: @om. You asked to remove dots that my solution can do. You have to use some tricks because you are trying to change orginal behavior of textarea element. I think my solution can help you.

Comment: @Zhansingsong provide the solution of my problem but firefox browser doesn't support that...

Answer (score 1):

try this but its `funny`, involves `draggin` and `div` ,

HTML Code

```
 <div id="d2" class="ui-widget-content" contenteditable>
        I look like textarea :)
    </div>
```

css Code

```
#d2{
-moz-appearance: textfield;
    -webkit-appearance: textfield;
    background-color: white;
    background-color: -moz-field;
    border: 1px solid darkgray;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px 0 lightgray inset;  
    font: -moz-field;
    font: -webkit-small-control;
    margin-top: 5px;
    padding: 2px 3px;
    width: 300px;
    height: 200px;
}
```

jquery Code

```
$(function() {
    $( "#d2" ).draggable({revert: function(obj){
            if (obj === true) {
            // success

            return false;
        }
        else {
            // reverting
            var offset = $(this).offset();
            var xPos = offset.left;
            var yPos = offset.top;


            $("#d2").css("width", $("#d2").width()+xPos);
            $("#d2").css("height", $("#d2").height()+yPos ); 

            return true;
        }
    }});

    });
```

above code can do what you want but in different taste just drag to increase textarea(here div) to resize.

[jsfiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/Hashy/z2fmxzd3/)